# How can I check that css, javascript and images are not expiring straight away

Tags: java, html, tomcat

I followed this guide to set an expiration filter to make javascript, images and css get cached by the bowser.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html

How can I now check that this is working. I am using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- load the page which has css and js included after clearing cache of the browser or incognito mode
- open inspect element
- goto network tab
- see the GET made to load those resources
- once they are loaded for the first time
- try loading the same page again (if those are cached it will not make a real request)

Comment: Fantastic. it even says "from cache"